# By which equivalent circuit (RC serie or RL serie) can I substitute the following circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

I was trying to solve the following question:
"Assuming that  = ,  = ,  = ,  =
,   =  rad/s, tell if the circuit can be substituted by an equivalent RC serie or RL serie circuit"

[image]

First thing I did was calculate the impedance for this circuit and I got: $Z_{aa'}$=$10^3-j80$. But what can I conclude from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real part of the impedance $Z_{aa'}$ is resistive so all you need to decide as to what component, inductor or capacitor, you would assign a negative imaginary part to.
Perhaps do it by a process of elimination or write down the general formulae for the reactances of capacitors and inductors?

Comment: Oh I see. So I guess I should substitute by an equivalent RC serie circuit, since the impendance of a capacitor is $\frac{1}{j\omega C}=-j\frac{1}{\omega C}$, with impendance equal to $80$?